# React project is not displaying text as I intend

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, bundler, parceljs

I am using Material UI TextInput component with a placeholder prop that passes the text **"Contraseña"**; The letter **ñ** in the word is not rendering as intended, but as **\fx1**. The HTLM header have meta UTF-8 and I am using **parcel 2.0.0-rc.0** as my bundler

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="APP"
      content="web site created using react"
    />
    <script src="~/src/index.js" type="module"></script>
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <TextField color="secondary" margin="none" placeholder="Contraseña" />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://material-ui.com/guides/localization/

Comment: Have you checked what your editor's encoding is?  In VSCode, this would be on the bottom right toolbar next to the tab size.  Make sure this is set to `utf-8`.

Comment: My vs code is set to UTF-8

Comment: I changed the Localization in Material UI (esES) but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the use of Parcel 2 RC ([Bug report](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6820)). It is important to notice that the bad encoding occurs only in attribute values; a temporary solution is to put brackets around the string attribute value:

```
<TextField color="secondary" margin="none" placeholder={"Contraseña"} />
```